# can't uninstall packages

Tags: r, uninstallation, install.packages

Hi I uninstalled a package but it still look accessible, can somebody help please? Thank u!

```
> remove.packages("RODBC")
Removing package from ‘E:/R/R-3.3.3/library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

> library(RODBC)
# no error. it's still there

> attr(sessionInfo()$otherPkgs$RODBC, "file")
[1] "E:/R/R-3.3.3/library/RODBC/Meta/package.rds"
# it really is there...


> remove.packages("dplyr")
Removing package from ‘E:/R/R-3.3.3/library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
> library(dplyr)
Error in library(dplyr) : there is no package called ‘dplyr’
# this guy is removed


> .Library
[1] "E:/R/R-3.3.3/library"

> .libPaths()
[1] "E:/R/R-3.3.3/library"
```

Would it be possible that the package `RODBC` was in use so that can not be removed?

Comment: What is your `.libPaths()`?

Comment: thank you@HongOoi   see update in OP please

Comment: What does `attr(sessionInfo()$otherPkgs$RODBC, "file")` return after you have uninstalled it but then called library? Did the remove work? There was no error about files being in use?

Comment: thank u @MrFlick i tired your code: it does seem to show the package is still there. I guess the removing didn't work. Do you know how to fix please?

Comment: You could restart R and try `remove.packages` again. Or just delete the RODBC directory via Explorer. It's just a normal directory, nothing special about it.

Answer (score 4):

this has happened to me before and I think what I did was literally go find the package's folder from file explorer on my computer and manually delete it

Comment: I agree, removing the specific folders of the packages is the most brute force way of  doing it.

Answer (score 1):

### Possible causes

There could be many reasons as to why it is happening.

In my case, `remove.packages("somepackagehere")` was not working because the current system user that I am using  doesn't have `write` privileges to the packages I want to uninstall. So, this is a possible reason for computers/machines with multiple users using R.

### Checking the location of packages

This can be checked by issuing the statement in the R console:

```
.libPaths()
```

**output**

```
[1] "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library"
```

The directory output may vary per R installation. This is just for my case. The directory output is where the installed packages were stored. It may look different for **Windows** systems.

### Checking privileges

In **Mac** and **Linux**, the privileges can be checked by:

```sh
cd /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library
ls -la
```

**output**

```
drwxrwxr-x  422 root         admin  13504 Apr 21 19:13 .
drwxrwxr-x   18 root         admin    576 Jul 16  2020 ..
drwxr-xr-x    3 mario        admin     96 Jun 17  2021 RODBC
drwxr-xr-x    3 mario        admin     96 Jun 17  2021 dplyr
```

In this case, it was `mario` who installed the packages. Since I --`luigi`-- was currently using the machine, I can not remove those packages. It is only `mario` that can do it.

In **Windows**, I have no clue as to how it can be checked.

### Granting privileges

```sh
cd /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library
sudo chown -R luigi:admin .
```

**OR**

```sh
cd /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library
sudo chmod -R o+w .
```

In **Windows**, I have no clue as to how privileges can be granted.

### Removing packages

Finally, with the correct privileges, you can now remove the packages like so:

```
remove.packages("RODBC")
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same trouble, so I try to delete packages by hand, but found I haven't root authority. Then I close R, and start it with sudo, try to remove packages again. However, it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Also had problems with `remove.packages` so deleting the folders as suggested by @sweetmusicality worked for me:

```
#e.g. remove packages associated with tidyverse
pkremove <- tools::package_dependencies("tidyverse", db = installed.packages())$tidyverse
lapply(pkremove, function(x) {
  unlink(paste0(.libPaths()[1], "/", x), recursive = TRUE) 
})
```